# Why does -O2 or greater optimization in clang break this code?

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, compiler-optimization, c++-chrono

I checked similar questions on the site, but I couldn't find anything that matches my scenario here. This is the code I'm trying to run (requires C++14):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class countdownTimer {
public:
    using duration_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration;

    countdownTimer(duration_t duration) : duration{ duration }, paused{ true } {}

    countdownTimer(const countdownTimer&)               = default;
    countdownTimer(countdownTimer&&)                    = default;
    countdownTimer& operator=(countdownTimer&&)         = default;
    countdownTimer& operator=(const countdownTimer&)    = default;

    void start() noexcept {
        if (started) return;
        startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        endTime = startTime + duration;
        started = true;
        paused = false;
    }

    void pause() noexcept {
        if (paused || !started) return;
        pauseBegin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        paused = true;
    }

    void resume() noexcept {
        if (!paused || !started) return;
        auto pauseDuration = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - pauseBegin;
        startTime += pauseDuration;
        endTime += pauseDuration;
        paused = false;
    }

    double remainingSeconds() const noexcept {
        auto ret = double{ 0.0 };
        if (!started) ret = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(duration).count();
        else if (paused) ret = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(duration - (pauseBegin - startTime)).count();
        else ret = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(duration - (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime)).count();
        return (ret < 0.0) ? 0.0 : ret;
    }

    duration_t remainingTime() const noexcept {
        auto ret = duration_t{ 0ms };
        if (!started) ret = chrono::duration_cast<duration_t>(duration);
        else if (paused) ret = chrono::duration_cast<duration_t>(duration - (pauseBegin - startTime));
        else ret = chrono::duration_cast<duration_t>(duration - (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime));
        return (ret < 0ms) ? 0ms : ret;
    }

    bool isPaused() const noexcept { return paused; }

    bool hasFinished() const noexcept { return remainingTime() == 0s; }

    void reset() noexcept {
        started = false;
        paused = true;
    }

private:
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pauseBegin;
    duration_t duration;
    bool paused;
    bool started;
};

int main() {
    countdownTimer timer(10s);
    timer.start();

    while (!timer.hasFinished()) {
        cout << timer.remainingSeconds() << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

It's a simple countdown timer class that I wrote for one of my projects. The client code in `main()` is pretty self-explanatory, it should output a countdown from 10 to 0, and then exit the program. With no optimization or `-O`/`-O1`, it does exactly that:

```
10
8.99495
7.98992
6.9849
5.97981
4.9748
3.96973
2.9687
1.9677
0.966752
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But if I step up the optimization to >=`-O2`, the program just keeps outputting 10, and runs forever. The countdown simply doesn't work, it's stuck at the starting value.

I'm using the latest Xcode on OS X. `clang --version` says `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)`.

The strange part is that my code doesn't contain any weird self-written loops, undefined behavior, or anything like that, it's pretty much just standard library calls, so it's very strange that optimization breaks it.

Any ideas?

PS: I haven't tried it on other compilers, but I'm about to. I'll update the question with those results.

Comment: Optimization levels shouldn't actually break your code's behavior unless you introduced undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but I don't really see where that could be. If it's that, it must be something very subtle that I'm failing to notice.

Comment: Note to people attempting to reproduce the problem: this code needs to be compiled with `-std=c++14` or higher.

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: you can actually compare the generated code by the different optimization levels and see where it actually differs.

Comment: @adam10603 Use a good profiling or static code analysis tool to find out potential sources.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm kind of familiar with perf on Linux, I might try that.

Comment: @adam10603 On linux try valgrind rather.

Comment: If your code is c++11 based, you can see different assembly generated here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/ for a quick check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is in your constructor:

```
 countdownTimer(duration_t duration)
 : duration{ duration }, paused{ true } {}
```

You forgot to initialize `started`.  This triggers undefined behavior when you call `start()`.

No version of clang that I have convenient access to will diagnose this error, but GCC versions 5 and 6 (on Linux - I don't have GCC on my Mac anymore) will:

```
$ g++ -O2 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:18:13: warning: ‘*((void*)& timer +33)’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
         if (started) return;
             ^~~~~~~
test.cc:74:20: note: ‘*((void*)& timer +33)’ was declared here
     countdownTimer timer(10s);
                    ^~~~~
```

(My copy of Xcode seems to be a bit out of date, with `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`; it does not change the behavior of the program at `-O2`. It's possible that *your* clang would diagnose this error if you turned on the warnings.)

(I have filed a [bug report with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72826) about the IR gobbledygook in the diagnostics.)

Comment: Ah... I didn't bother to initialize it, since I assign a value to it in `start()`, but I actually inserted the check at the beginning at `start()` afterwards, and I didn't think that over again.

Comment: Why doesn't this cause any trouble at a lower optimization level?

Comment: Whatever optimization pass exposed the problem was not enabled at lower optimization levels.  Answering in any more detail would require digging through intermediate-stage debugging dumps, and I don't know how to do that with clang (and I don't have the right version of clang to do it with, either).

Answer (score 9):

`bool started` is not initialized.
If you initialize it to `false`, it works with `-O2`:

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a511ca99ae4caa8)</kbd>

You can find errors like this using the Undefined behavior sanitizer:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -g -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp:18:9: runtime error: load of value 106, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
```